# Jade Agent cannot receive multi msg

Tags: pug, agent, agents-jade

I have a problem with receiving multi messages with one Agent.
the following is my code. msg_r, which Agent receive is always the first message. how can I get the second message from `getSender().getLocalName().equals("TeilsystemAgent")`

```
public class KomponenteAgent extends Agent {
    static JTextArea txt = gui.gettxt();
    private String AdminReceive = "";
    private String KompCheckReceive = "";
    private int Zaehler = 0;
    JSONArray Admin = new JSONArray();
    JSONArray KompCheck = new JSONArray();

protected void setup() {
    Object[] arg = getArguments();
    //frame = (IAPMS)arg[0];

    addBehaviour(new SimpleBehaviour(this) {
        private boolean finished = false;
        public void action() {
            ACLMessage msg_r = receive();               
            if (msg_r!= null){
                if (msg_r.getSender().getLocalName().equals("KoordinatorAgent"))
                    //Bestaetigung                                              
                    try {
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    AdminReceive = AdminReceive + msg_r.getContent();
                    try {
                        Admin = new JSONArray(AdminReceive);
                        System.out.println(getLocalName()+ Admin);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Zaehler = Zaehler + 1;
                }   

            if (msg_r!= null ){
                if (msg_r.getSender().getLocalName().equals("TeilsystemAgent"))
                    //Bestaetigung                                              
                    try {
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }                       
                KompCheckReceive = KompCheckReceive + msg_r.getContent();
                System.out.println(getLocalName()+ KompCheckReceive);
                try {
                    KompCheck = new JSONArray(KompCheckReceive);
                    System.out.println(getLocalName()+ KompCheck);
                    checkKomp(KompCheck);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if (Zaehler == 1){
            finished = true;
            }
        }

        public boolean done(){
            return finished;
        }

    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In JADE you should note that messages are treated as FIFO within the queue. which means that a generic receive without a MessageTemplate search of your message queue, the Agent will just take the message that has been in its queue the longest. it seems your behaviour will complete after receiving a message from KoordinatorAgent. Thus, if your Agent receives a KoordinatorAgent message first, it will be processed first and the boolean will be triggered for your behaviour to end.

Instead, to recieve multiple messages of different forms, implement MessageTemplates in the order in which you need to recieve them:

```
ACLMessage msg_r = receive(MessageTemplate.MatchSender(new AID(TeilsystemAgent, ISLOCALNAME)));
if(msg_r != null){
   // Treat incomming message as required
   TeilsystemAgent_messageCounter++;
}

if(TeilsystemAgent_messageCounter == expectedNumberofMessages){
   msg_r = receive(MessageTemplate.MatchSender(new AID(KoordinatorAgent, ISLOCALNAME)));
   // treat message as required
   Zaehler = Zaehler + 1;
}
```

Altenatively, tweak your "behaviour complete" satifsfaction criteria. so you can recieve messages from both agents but recieve multiple messages without completing.